# Extracting the space between polygons

Tags: python, geojson, geometry, geopandas

I have a GeoJSON file and I was able to extract the space where there are some obstacles, e.g., forest.

[image]

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union

gdf = gpd.read_file('/home/jovyan/work/Export3.geojson')

wood_poly = []
for polygon, model_type in zip(gdf["geometry"], gdf["natural"]):
    if(model_type == "wood"):
        wood_poly.append(polygon)

fig2 = plt.figure(2, dpi=90)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)

wood_cascade = cascaded_union(wood_poly)
wood = gpd.GeoSeries(wood_cascade)
wood.plot(ax=ax2, color = 'red')
wood.boundary.plot(color="black", edgecolor='k', linewidth = 2, ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

**Problem:** Now I want to separate out the free space, i.e., space which is shown in white colour. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try unary_union to dissolve all obstacles to a big multipolygon. Then create a rectangle around the multipolygon and difference:

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file(r'C:\GIS\data\tempdata\my.shp')

multipolygon = df.geometry.unary_union
envelope = multipolygon.envelope

diff = envelope.difference(multipolygon)
```

[image]